# Adding to the bottom of a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have this program which emulates a stack, I've used a `listbox` to represent this, the only problem is when I add the first element, it adds to the top of the `listbox` rather than the bottom.

> This is what my program looks like:

[image]

The **red** is where the elements are being added, the **green** is where the elements should be added

The function I need to change is `Add()`, I've added the whole code anyway because there's not a lot and anyone can copy it.

As for the problem, I've tried `stack.insert("end", data)`, I've tried `stack.insert(END, data)` but it still adds to the top of the listbox

> Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *

Window = Tk() # window

Window.geometry("400x200+50+50") # heightxwidth+x+y
Window.title("Stack Emulator")

mainPanel = Canvas(Window, width = 400, height = 200) # :)
mainPanel.pack() # :)

global stack
stack = Listbox(height = 8)

# methods
def Add(data):
    data = data.get()
    stack.insert(0, data)
    stack.see(0)

def Remove():
    stack.delete(0)
    stack.see(0)

# buttons   
data = StringVar()
enter = Entry(width = 10, textvariable = data)
add = Button(text = "Push", command = lambda *args: Add(data))
remove = Button(text = "Pop", command = lambda *args: Remove())

# stack
mainPanel.create_text(100, 20, text = "Stack", font = ("Purisa", 14, "bold"))
mainPanel.create_window(100, 35, window = stack, anchor = "n")
mainPanel.create_rectangle(37, 34, 162, 167)

# methods
mainPanel.create_text(180, 40, text = "Element:", font = ("Purisa", 12), anchor = "nw")
mainPanel.create_window(250, 40, window = enter, anchor = "nw")
mainPanel.create_window(180, 60, window = add, anchor = "nw")
mainPanel.create_window(180, 90, window = remove, anchor = "nw")
```

Answer (score 1):

As @BryanOakley points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40947039/21945) the list box does not normally allow rows to be added at the bottom of the list box widget. There is a work-around though, and that is to first pad the box with empty strings, and then to add/delete to/from the end using `END`:

```
#global stack
stack = Listbox(height=8)
stack.count = 0
# fill the listbox with empty lines
for i in range(stack.cget('height')-1):
    stack.insert(END, '')

# methods
def Add(data):
    stack.insert(END, data.get())
    stack.see(END)
    stack.count += 1

def Remove():
    if stack.count > 0:
        stack.delete(END)
        stack.see(END)
        stack.count -= 1
```

This code initialises the list box with enough empty lines such that a string appended to it will appear at the bottom. An attribute `count` is created on the listbox object to keep track of the number of items on the stack. This is so that popping an empty stack will not remove the padding lines.

Comment: This is a good way to do this, but my program has other features which get elements from the stack, I could do this but I think its more code than its worth. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The listbox doesn't work this way. You can only add items from the top down.

Comment: That's a shame :( That wasn't me with the down vote btw

Comment: Except that `insert(END, data)` actually works, as does `delete(END)`. There is some documentation backs that up, http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm, which states that using `END` appends to the list box.

Comment: @mhawke: yes, "end" (or the constant `END`) appends to the end of the listbox. The "end" of the listbox is not the same as the "bottom" of the listbox. The OP wants the data to scroll up from the bottom, rather than down from the top.